# Would a Syrian King have worn the toga after the Edict of Caracalla?

Tags: ancient-rome, literature

As you may know, the Edict of Caracalla granted citizenship to all freeborn citizens of the Roman Empire. I'm writing a novel set several decades after this edict, and one of the characters is a Syrian king. His family was known for being a  Romanized Arab family, but since the East was so Hellenized, would he have worn the toga that had long been a marker of citizenship, or worn eastern trousers and a chiton of regular Palmyrenes and Syrians at the time?

Comment: I think this might help you (refers primarily to the 3rd century): [What was clothing in ancient Palmyra like?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/46106/what-was-clothing-in-ancient-palmyra-like).

Comment: Not my field, but the status of "king" and "Roman citizen" can co-exist only long enough to fall from the Tarpenian rock.

Comment: Arab? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Mark C. Wallace  I presume that Lgndry was referring to the family of Septimius Odaenathus (c.220-267), who was a Roman citizen who became ruler of Palmayra, Roman leader of most of the East, and in 263 King of Kings of the East. He was the husband of Queen of Kings Zenobia, and father of King of Kings Hairan I, assassinated with his father, and King of Kings Vallbathus.  In 337 Emperor Constantine I appointed his nephew Hannibalianus King of Kings.  So by that era it was not impossible for a Roman citizen to become a king or a king of Kings.